# When do ASP.NET Core claims become accessible via HttpContext.User.Claims?

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

Setup:

1. Create a `ClaimsPrincipal` with a bunch of claims.
2. Call `httpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyAuthScheme", myClaimsPrincipal, myAuthProperties)`
3. Try to iterate through all claims on `httpContext.User.Claims`.

Result:

The claims from pt. 1 are not in the `httpContext.User.Claims`-collection.

Why?

EDIT:

```
var claims = GetPersistentClaims(username.ToLowerInvariant());
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
var authenticationManager = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication;
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties {IsPersistent = isPersistent};
await authenticationManager.SignInAsync(AuthenticationScheme, principal, properties);
// This is where I inspect _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.
```

Comment: What is the value of `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?

Comment: @adem caglin it's `false`.

Comment: Where and when do you iterate `httpContext.User.Claims`? If possible  could you post your code?

Comment: I've added a source code snippet.

Comment: iirc they become available in the request **after** the login, so you'd need to redirect the user to the new/protected resource after logging in with `SignInAsync`, because at the time you call `SignInAsync` the HttpContext is already set and the `User` property won't change until next request

Comment: @Tseng Thanks, that's working and all, but my question is "why aren't they available right after sign in"?

Comment: Because they are created in the middleware, which handles the request before its passed to MVC. Middlewares in ASP.NET Core are the ones you register with `UseIdentity` or `UseStaticFiles` or `UseMvc`. Each of them is a middleware and executed in the order it's registered

Answer (score 0):

When you call `SignInAsync`, the authentication handler calls own `SignInAsync()`. In your case it is cookie authentication(it just sets cookie).

If you want to authenticate user, you need to call `authenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticationScheme);`.

**Edit**

It didn't work after `SignInAsync` because there is no cookie for current request. But `HttpContext.User = principal ;` may be a solution.

ps : normally you use claims for next request.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same - and this worked back in Beta 8 and RC1 - but doesn't anymore. Frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I think I'll have to throw this in the "another thing that was changed and not documented" pile.